Should Children Obey Unrighteous Parents?
In this regard, I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XY3F1vGujNE posted on this blog: https://antaryamin.wordpress.com/2020/01/13/should-children-obey-unrighteous-parents/
But I don't understand any Tamil - a translation by a Tamil speaker would be useful. Anyhow, the question stands: should we obey parents who are unrighteous. Did Rama obey his unrighteous mother Kaikeyi or did he chose to obey his righteous father. Prahalad disobeyed his father by continuing to follow Lord Vishnu?

Disobey but never disrespect, that too provided it is clear on what is dharma.

Is there any scriptural reference to it?

I’m voting to close this question because questions about youtube videos should be addressed to the authors of those youtubes, the veracity of youtube videos is not a topic for this forum.

Parents should be worshiped, unrighteous parents should be worshiped from a distance.
